Logical replication not working and no errors in the logs
I have setup a logical replication in PostgreSQL and have made the changes in postgres.conf where i have set wal_level = 'logical'
The create subscription part works well but the create subscriber hangs and does not show any errors in the logs
Below is the command I am using to create a subscription
  CREATE SUBSCRIPTION SUB_NL_LIVE_NEW
  CONNECTION 'host=x.x.x.x port=5432 user=postgres password=xxx dbname=main sslmode=require'
  PUBLICATION NL_LIVE;

The above command hangs and nothing in the logs show. I have the following log settings
log_error_verbosity = verbose
log_min_messages = debug1


any help on what could be going wrong or how can i investigate this further
what is the recommend way to cleanup Publisher? does deleting the publication like below cleanup everything?

DROP PUBLICATION pub_name

Any help here would be really great, Thanks in advance.

Trying creating a replication slot manually at publisher side and specify it when creating subscription.

Are both databases in the same database cluster?

No the databases on two different servers

the replication slot gets created correctly on the publisher end @goodfella

I think you can check if the connection is working by the number of tables being published (for example, only one table is published).
